# How to find equal values in two different matrix/vectors?

Tags: matrix, octave

I would like to know if there is an equal value in 2 different matrix.
I tried to use the function `find` but, it transforms my `uint8` matrix in a logical matrix and it doesn't give me the position, and values of my elements in my vector. I precise that equals values are not situate in the same position in those 2 differents matrix.
Then currently, I tried this code :

```
B=imread("deformation_somb.jpg");%RGB pictures

xc=pixel_x1; % xc = nc/2
yc=pixel_y1; %yc = nr/2

j=nr-yc;
i=xc;
i_c=1;
j_c=1;
i_nouveau_h=i;
i_nouveau_b=i;
j_nouveau_d=j;
j_nouveau_g=j;
C_horizontale_droite=[];
C_horizontale_gauche=[];
C_verticale_haut=[];% 
C_verticale_bas=[];
C_horizontale_droite2=uint8(C_horizontale_droite)
C_horizontale_gauche2=uint8(C_horizontale_gauche)
C_verticale_haut2=uint8(C_verticale_haut)
C_verticale_bas2=uint8(C_verticale_bas)
while((i_nouveau_h!=nr-1) && (i_nouveau_b!=0) && (j_nouveau_g!=0) && (j_nouveau_d!=nc-1))
    C_horizontale_gauche2(1,j_c,:)=B(i+1,j_nouveau_g,:);
    C_horizontale_droite2(1,j_c,:)=B(i+2,j_nouveau_d,:);
    C_verticale_haut2(1,j_c,:)=B(i_nouveau_h,j,:);
    C_verticale_bas2(1,j_c,:)=B(i_nouveau_b,j,:); 
    i_nouveau_h = i_nouveau_h+1;
    i_nouveau_b = i_nouveau_b-1;
    j_nouveau_d = j_nouveau_d+1;
    j_nouveau_g = j_nouveau_g-1;
    j_c=j_c+1;
endwhile



% Responsable of LOGICAL!!!!
% distance_pixel_gauche_centre = find(C_horizontale_gauche=C_horizontale_droite!=0)
% distance_pixel_droite_centre = find(C_horizontale_droite=C_horizontale_gauche!=0);
% distance_pixel_haut_centre= find(C_verticale_haut=C_verticale_bas!=0);
% distance_pixel_bas_centre= find(C_verticale_bas=C_verticale_haut!=0);
```

Comment: Your code is non-functional. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What you want to do should be possible using linear and logical indexing. You should review the following and then come back with a mcve like @excaza asked.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html